# How to know the time at which a specific data

Tags: c++, wav

I have a program that reads WAV files and checks whether it's been tampered with using sha1. The program reads 42,000 bytes at a time for validation, is it possible to find the time range of that chunk of data?

Edit: the chunk of data is the data array that’s stored in a data struct of a RIFF fmt WAV file.  It’s read using an `fread` function then stored in a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: What do you mean "the time range of that chunk of data"? Which chunk of data?

Comment: You may need to read the wav file format specification and check how is data stored. You can check out this link: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

Comment: The [`"fmt "`](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) chunk of the WAVE file has a field `nAvgBytesPerSec`. I don't know how reliable this field is for compressed data, but at least for uncompressed data (e.g. `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM`), you should be able to calculate the time for a particular byte offset exactly.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: It ought to work for any Constant Bit Rate format. Uncompressed formats are a subset of CBR formats. But TBH using WAV (RIFF) for non-PCM data is just weird.